# jquery dynamic pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, jsonp

I have this script which allows to display Bing search results: [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz6wC/)

The problem is that it can only show up to 50 result at a time. So I want to make a pagination . So far I have this code which allows to display the second part of the results, with var WebOffset = "Web.Offset=0";

```
$("#page2").click(function() {
    WebOffset = "Web.Offset=1";
    var searchTerms = getSearch();
    doSearch(searchTerms);
});
```

My question: How can I predict how many results there are in total so that I would now how many pagination numbers (divs) to make. But more important this of course has to be 'automated'. So the code would have to display a set of divs(pagination numbers) based on the bing results in total. I really have no idea were to begin solving this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you must have some server side logic in order to get the results, you can request the number of results when a search query is submitted and store it, or, you can get that number with each page request. Also, since it appears you're using jQuery, this should be easy.

Here is what these two scenarios could look like:

First:

1. The user submits a search query
2. **The server returns the first page of results.**
3. **Get total number of results, for pagination controls**
4. The user clicks different page (send a request to the server with the page number)
5. The server returns the results that correspond to the currently selected page

And the second:

1. The user submits a search query
2. **The server returns the first page results, along with the total results count**
3. The user clicks different page (send a request to the server with the page number)
4. The server returns the results that correspond to the currently selected page

You can see that in the first scenario, you would have to store the total result count on the client side. As opposed to the second one, where you receive it with every result request.

Home this helps. Have a great day!

Comment: I think I made a mistake in my question... the total number results is already given...If you type 'stack' you will see (top right above results) 'Showing 10 of 133000000 results' I appreciate you took the time and effort to explain, but I already know how the request is made, I just need to know how to paginate

Comment: I see. If you have total result count(T) and the number of desired results per page(N), by dividing T by N, you will get the total number of pages(P). This number will determine how many div's you will need to add (assuming this number is small, like <10). However, since there are some many pages, this won't be an option. Assuming the current page is K, you can render the pages from (K - x) to (K + x). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You're very welcome.Let me know how it works out, or if there is anything else.